# How to compare the output of my task with a desired action?

Tags: ansible

I am using Ansible and for a test I would like to compare the output of each task with a "dictionary"

Example:

```
TASK [Do something] ********************************************
--- before
+++ after
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
 {
-    "mode": "010",
+    "mode": "030",
     "path": "/root/power.doc"
 }

changed: [Machine] => (item=/root/power.doc)
```

I have this output from the task on the log file.

How can I create a task which can read the log and check if the part of the task `+    "mode": "030"` is correctly there ?

Comment: From your current example: you write a playbook where you define what the state of a particular file should be. This includes that the file mode should be `0030` (side note: you should always have a leading 0 for modes in ansible). You run your playbook to align the state of a remote host to the one you described. And now you want to make sure that the state you described is the one that was set on the the target if it changed? Either you don't trust yourself and I can't help, or you don't trust ansible and you should use an other tool. Did I miss something?

Comment: yes you got my goal !
It is simply to check if the after from the diff will be the right one and are not modified by someone or something

Answer (score 0):

You cannot write a task a in the playbook to check the logs of the playbook run. One option could be to possibly redirect the output to a file, then parse that file for what you want with the tool of your choice.

*However if you want to write a task to check and validate that the mode was indeed what you wanted to set.* Then you can use the [assert module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/assert_module.html).

I am not sure what your previous task `Do something` does, but just for sake of example, I am going to set some mode.

Example:

```yaml
- file:
    path: "/tmp/somefile"
    state: "touch"
    mode: "0755"
  register: file_details
- assert:
    that:
    - file_details.mode == "0755"
  fail_msg: "File *does not* have correct permissions!"
  success_msg: "File permissions are correct."
```